# Maven writes Dependencies to my projects's root folder. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, package, dependencies

When I want to package my Java source code and I run `mvn clean package`, the dependencies get pulled from the public maven repository. But instead of them ending up in the local `.m2` repository, they are being written directly to my project's root folder. How can I resolve this?

[image: Repository dependencies being added to the module's root folder]

The Pom.xml file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <artifactId>sample-docker-spark-job</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.me.compute</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <main.class>org.me.compute.consumer.TwitterConnSparkConsumer</main.class>
        <maven-shade-plugin.version>3.2.3</maven-shade-plugin.version>
        <maven.surefire.plugin.version>3.0.0-M4</maven.surefire.plugin.version>
        <org.junit.jupiter.version>5.4.0</org.junit.jupiter.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.12</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.dependency.scope>compile</spark.dependency.scope>
        <spark.version>3.0.0</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>${spark.dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>${spark.dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>${spark.dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>${spark.dependency.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Run Junit tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.plugin.version}</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.junit.jupiter.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <!-- To generate an Uber Jar -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-shade-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                        <exclude>scala/**</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.txt</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                                        <exclude>*.conf</exclude>
                                        <exclude>scripts/*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Pack JAR to a TAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-to-tar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>src/assembly/tar.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Let me mention that in my .m2 repository there is no settings.xml file.

[image: No settings.xml file found]

Furthermore, here is a screenshot of my maven settings in IntelliJ IDEA:

[image]

I have already tried to delete my local repository and clone afresh from the remote, but that did not help either, although the remote contains no preconfigured `.idea` folder or something like that but only source code. Afterwards I tried with a different sample repository and the issue is the same, so apparently it must me **linked to my general maven config** and not to the repository itself. I am grateful for any advice!

Comment: You Maven config will be helpful, otherwise can only guess.

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Comment: I have added the pom file to the question.

Comment: Do you use a `settings.xml`? Could you add that as well?

Comment: I don't think I have a settings.xml file somewhere. Didn't create one myself and looked a bit through the repository but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There must be a `settings.xml` file...it looks like you have configured something strange... please search for the file in your `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml` and post it here...

Comment: I have now added a screenshot in which is shown that I don't have a settings.xml file in my .m2 repository.

Comment: Please attach screenshot from "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven".

Comment: I have now added a screenshot from my maven settings in IntelliJ IDEA also.

Comment: Please share settings file from "C:\Users\Rockem\.m2"

Comment: As mentioned and shown in my post, in my .m2 repository there is no settings.xml file.

Comment: Do you face the same issue if you run "mvn clean package" from command line outside IDE?

Comment: Just tried, yes this happens too if I open CMD and run "mvn clean package" from there.

Comment: Is it reproducible with some new sample project (without plugins and with single dependency)?